# Accept new connection after client close(C, winsock2)

Tags: c, http, winsock, tcp, winsock2

I have a simple HTTP Server on winsock2.

I send Get request from my brouser to server and get response with content. After that a brouser close connection and send new request. What I have to do to accept new connection?

I try

```
connectEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSAEventSelect( sHttp, connectEvent, FD_READ);
WSANETWORKEVENTS netevent;

WSAEventSelect(sHttp,connectEvent, FD_ACCEPT);
WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &connectEvent, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
WSAEnumNetworkEvents(sHttp,connectEvent,&netevent);
if (netevent.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE){
    printf("closed\n");
    closesocket(sHttp);
}
if (netevent.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT){
    printf("accepted\n");
    struct sockaddr_in client = {};
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);
    sHttp =  accept(sHttp, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    WSAEventSelect(sHttp,connectEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);
}
```

but connection is not accepted

Comment: 'connection is not accepted' and the error from WSAGetLastError is?

Comment: I am in the endless waiting

Comment: If `sHttp` is your listening socket, why are you overwriting it with the return from `accept`? (Presumably, to accept more connections, you need to use your listening socket)

Comment: after listen(sHttp,SOMAXCONN) listening socket I don't need and I override it

Comment: what socket should I use in WSAEventSelect? Listening or accept?

Comment: If you want to accept new connections, use the listening socket.